# Add axes with ticks and without labels in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I got the following chart in ggplot:

```
library(ggplot2)
a <- seq(1,20)
b <- a^0.25
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(a,b))

ggplot(df, aes(x = a, y = b)) + geom_point()
```

Question: How can I add axes to the top and to the right of the plot, with ticks, but not with labels (as the labels are on the bottom and on the left already), and also with white background? If I use `+ theme_classic()`, the background becomes white, but the axes on the top and right are also removed.

Comment: to clarify, do you still want x and y axes with labels in the bottom left?

Comment: @astrofunkswag yes indeed, the left (y) and bottom (x) axes should stay (unchanged). So essentially I want a full rectangle in terms of axes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for `dup_axis`

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = a, y = b)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(sec.axis = dup_axis(name = NULL, labels = NULL)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = dup_axis(name = NULL, labels = NULL)) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

EDIT: I wasn't clear on whether you wanted tick labels, you can add them back by removing the `labels = NULL`